# Как вывести ФИО сотрудников вместо чисел столбца Kod_sotr

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: Talbe]

Я сделал программу, которая отображает данные о хранилище фруктов в Grid, я хочу, чтобы вместо чисел в столбце Kod_sotr отображался ФИО, а также удалить последние два столбца?

Класс который Выводиться

```
 class FruitStorage
    {
        [Key]
        public int FruitStorageKod { get; set; }
        public int Kod_sotr {get;set;}
        public int Kod_cell { get; set; }
       public int Kod_chamber { get; set; }
       public  DateTime Date_fill { get; set; }
        public virtual Sotr Sotr { get; set; }    
        public virtual Сhamber Chamber { get; set; }
   

    }
```

Присвоение форме

```
  List<FruitStorage> Interface1.fruitOut
     {
            set => dataGridView.DataSource = value;
        }



public FruitSoragePresenter()
        {
            var fruit = new FruitS<FruitStorage>();
           
            fruit.Show();
          
            
        }


 public FruitSoragePresenter(Interface1 view)
        {


            sotrView.fruitOut = db.FuitStorages.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Сделайте функцию, которая будет подгружать по данному коду нужную вам персону. Я не понимаю с каким вы инструментом всё же работаете, но если это база данных, то у вас нету связи между данным полем и конкретным человеком.

Comment: Я использую entity-framework и sql server.                                                               
 Есть связь в классе Sotr:  public ICollection<FruitStorage> fruit_Storages2 { get; set; }    В sql коде на серваке : CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.FruitStorages_dbo.Sotrs_Kod_sotr] FOREIGN KEY ([Kod_sotr]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Sotrs] ([Kod_sotr]) ON DELETE CASCADE,

Comment: Скройте второй и последний столбец: `dataGridView.Columns["Kod_sotr"].Visible = false;` - таким образом. В столбце `Sotr` уже содержится то, что вам нужно.